# Вопрос подключения избранного и подписок в django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Проект из учебы, сайт с рецептами, никак не могу подключить добавление в избранное, подписки и не создается новый рецепт(не подтягиваются тэги и ингредиенты), я уже всю голову сломал, не могу найти проблему. Подписки отдают 404, избранные отдают 500 (не разрешен метод `get`).

вьюха

```
from datetime import datetime
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

from recipes.models import (FavoritesList, Ingredients, IngredientInRecipe,
                            Recipe, ShoppingList, Tag
                            )

from .filters import IngredientFilter, RecipeFilter
from .permissions import IsAdminOrReadOnly, IsAuthorOrReadOnly
from .pagination import CatsPagination
from .serializers import (CreateRecipeSerializer, FavoriteSerializer,
                          IngredientSerializer, RecipeSerializer,
                          ShoppingListSerializer, TagSerializer
                          )


class TagViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)


class IngredientsViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """Получить список всех категорий"""
    queryset = Ingredients.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IngredientSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
    filter_backends = (IngredientFilter)
    filterset_class = IngredientFilter


class RecipeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ Операции с рецептами """
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthorOrReadOnly | IsAdminOrReadOnly, )
    pagination_class = CatsPagination
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filterset_class = RecipeFilter

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return RecipeSerializer
        return CreateRecipeSerializer

    @staticmethod
    def post_method_for_actions(request, pk, serializers):
        """ Метод добавления """
        data = {'user': request.user.id, 'recipe': pk}
        serializer = serializers(data=data, context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    @staticmethod
    def delete_method_for_actions(request, pk, model):
        """ Метод удаления """
        obj = model.objects.filter(user=request.user, recipe__id=pk)
        obj.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def shopping_cart(self, request, pk):
        """ Добавить в список покупок """
        return self.post_method_for_actions(
            request, pk, serializers=ShoppingListSerializer
        )

    @shopping_cart.mapping.delete
    def delete_shopping_cart(self, request, pk):
        """ Удалить из списка покупок """
        return self.delete_method_for_actions(
            request=request, pk=pk, model=ShoppingList)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def favorite(self, request, pk):
        """ Добавить в избранное """
        return self.post_method_for_actions(
            request=request, pk=pk, serializers=FavoriteSerializer)

    @favorite.mapping.delete
    def delete_favorite(self, request, pk):
        """ Удалить из избранного """
        return self.delete_method_for_actions(
            request=request, pk=pk, model=FavoritesList)

    @action(
        detail=False, methods=['get'], permission_classes=(IsAuthenticated,)
    )
    def download_shopping_cart(self, request):
        """ Скачать рецепт """
        user = request.user
        if not user.shopping_list.exists():
            return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        ingredients = IngredientInRecipe.objects.filter(
            recipe__shopping_list__user=request.user
        ).values(
            'ingredient__name',
            'ingredient__measurement_unit'
        ).annotate(amount=Sum('amount'))

        today = datetime.today()
        shopping_list = (
            f'Список покупок для: {user.get_full_name()}\n\n'
            f'Дата: {today:%Y-%m-%d}\n\n'
        )
        shopping_list += '\n'.join([
            f'- {ingredient["ingredient__name"]}'
            f'({ingredient["ingredient__measurement_unit"]})'
            f' - {ingredient["amount"]}'
            for ingredient in ingredients
        ])
        shopping_list += f'\n\nFoodgram ({today:%Y})'

        filename = f'{user.username}_shopping_list.txt'
        response = HttpResponse(shopping_list, content_type='text/plain')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={filename}'
        return response
```

сериализатор

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import transaction
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer, UserSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework.fields import SerializerMethodField
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.relations import PrimaryKeyRelatedField

from recipes.models import (FavoritesList, Follow, Ingredients,
                            IngredientInRecipe, Recipe, Tag, ShoppingList)
from users.models import User


class CustomUserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор создания пользователя. """
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name',
                  'last_name', 'password'
                  )


class CustomUserSerializer(UserSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор модели пользователя. """
    is_subscribed = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'first_name',
                  'last_name', 'is_subscribed'
                  )

    def get_is_subscribed(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request is not None and (
            request.user.is_authenticated and Follow.objects.filter(
                user=request.user, author=obj
            ).exists()
        )


class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор просмотра тегов"""
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'color', 'slug')


class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredients
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'measurement_unit')


class IngredientRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор связи ингридиентов и рецепта"""
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='ingredient.id')
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='ingredient.name')
    measurement_unit = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='ingredient.measurement_unit'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = IngredientInRecipe
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'measurement_unit', 'amount')


class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор для просмотра рецепта"""
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
    author = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    ingredients = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_favorited = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        method_name='get_is_favorited')
    is_in_shopping_cart = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        method_name='get_is_in_shopping_cart')

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id', 'tags', 'author', 'ingredients',
                  'is_favorited', 'is_in_shopping_cart',
                  'name', 'image', 'text', 'cooking_time'
                  )

    def get_ingredients(self, obj):
        ingredients = IngredientInRecipe.objects.filter(recipe=obj)
        return IngredientRecipeSerializer(ingredients, many=True).data

    def get_is_favorited(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request is not None and (
            request.user.is_authenticated and FavoritesList.objects.filter(
                user=request.user, recipe__id=obj.id).exists())

    def get_is_in_shopping_cart(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request is not None and (
            request.user.is_authenticated and ShoppingList.objects.filter(
                user=request.user, recipe__id=obj.id).exists())


class AddIngredientRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор добавление ингридиентов в рецепт """
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    amount = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = IngredientInRecipe
        fields = ('id', 'amount')


class CreateRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор  создания, редактирования и удаления рецепта"""
    author = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    ingredients = AddIngredientRecipeSerializer(many=True)
    tags = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(), many=True)
    image = Base64ImageField(use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'ingredients', 'tags',
                  'image', 'name', 'text', 'cooking_time'
                  )

    def create_ingredients(self, ingredients, recipe):
        IngredientInRecipe.objects.bulk_create(
            [IngredientInRecipe(
                ingredient=Ingredients.objects.get(id=ingredient['id']),
                recipe=recipe,
                amount=ingredient['amount']
            ) for ingredient in ingredients]
        )

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        """ Создание рецепта """
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
        ingredients = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        author = self.context.get('request').user
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(
            author=author, **validated_data
        )
        self.create_ingredients(recipe=recipe, ingredients=ingredients)
        recipe.tags.set(tags)
        return recipe

    @transaction.atomic
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """ Изменение рецепта """
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
        ingredients = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        instance.tags.clear()
        instance.tags.set(tags)
        instance.ingredients.clear()
        self.create_ingredients(recipe=instance,
                                ingredients=ingredients
                                )
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return RecipeSerializer(instance, context={
            'request': self.context.get('request')
        }).data


class RecipeShortInfo(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор отображения избранного """
    image = Base64ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image', 'cooking_time')


class ShoppingListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор списка покупок """
    class Meta:
        model = ShoppingList
        fields = ('recipe', 'user')

    def validate(self, data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        recipe = data['recipe']
        if ShoppingList.objects.filter(
            user=request.user, recipe=recipe
        ).exists():
            raise ValidationError({
                'errors': 'Рецепт уже есть в корзине.'
            })
        return data

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return RecipeShortInfo(instance.recipe, context={
            'request': self.context.get('request')
        }).data


class FavoriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор избранного """
    class Meta:
        model = FavoritesList
        fields = ('user', 'recipe')

    def validate(self, data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if not request or request.user.is_anonymous:
            return False
        recipe = data['recipe']
        if recipe in request.user.recipes.all():
            raise ValidationError({
                'errors': 'Уже есть в избранном.'
            })
        return data

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return RecipeShortInfo(instance.recipe, context={
            'request': self.context.get('request')
        }).data


class FollowListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор списка подписок """
    recipes = SerializerMethodField()
    recipes_count = SerializerMethodField()
    is_subscribed = SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email', 'id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name',
            'is_subscribed', 'recipes', 'recipes_count'
        )

    def get_recipes_count(self, author):
        return Recipe.objects.filter(author=author).count()

    def get_recipes(self, author):
        queryset = self.context.get('request')
        recipes_limit = queryset.query_params.get(
            'recipes_limit', settings.RECIPES_LIMIT)
        return RecipeShortInfo(
            Recipe.objects.filter(author=author)[recipes_limit],
            many=True,
            context={'request': queryset}
        ).data

    def get_is_subscribed(self, author):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request.user.subscriber.all().exists()


class FollowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор подписки"""
    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        fields = ('user', 'author')

    def validate(self, data):
        get_object_or_404(User, username=data['author'])
        if self.context['request'].user == data['author']:
            raise ValidationError({
                'errors': 'На себя подписаться нельзя.'
            })
        if Follow.objects.filter(
                user=self.context['request'].user,
                author=data['author']
        ):
            raise ValidationError({
                'errors': 'Вы уже подписан.'
            })
        return data

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return FollowListSerializer(
            instance.author,
            context={'request': self.context.get('request')}
        ).data
```